# csrf Token class

Tags: php, html, csrf

can someone explain me how to protect the profile page from the wrong user editing the URL to see some other users profile page. i am using a token class to generate a random number to protect against Cross Site Request Forgery. for some reason it doesn't work any suggestion or other way to do that

Also i get the following error : Undefined index: token in PhpProject22_CSRF\profile.php on line 12

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'Classes/Token.php';
$tk = new Token();

if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['product'],$_POST['token'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
if(!empty($product) && !empty($username)){
    if(Token::check($_POST['token'])){
        echo $_POST['token'].'<br>';
        $tk->get('username');
        $_SESSION['user'] = $tk->name();
        echo 'Process Order';
    }
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CSRF Protection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="product">
            <strong>Profile</strong>
            <div class='field'>
                Username: <input type='text' name='username'>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Order'>
            <input type='hidden' name='product' value='1'>
            <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate();?>'>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    ?>
    <p>Hello <a href = 'profile.php?user=<?php echo $tk->name();?>'><?php echo $tk-  >name();?></a>!</p>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
class Token{
private $_data;

public static function generate(){
    return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
}

public static function check($token){
    if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token']){      
        unset($_SESSION['token']);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($item){
    if(isset($_POST[$item])){
        $this->_data = $_POST[$item];
    }
}

public function name(){
return $this->_data;
}
}
?>

<?php
require_once 'Classes/Token.php';
session_start();
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate();?>'>
</form>

<?php
echo 'Hello '.$_SESSION['user'].'!<br>';
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
if(Token::check($_POST['token'])){
    echo $_GET['user'];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: put `session_start()` in your token class functions.

Comment: You should also check the CSRF on EVERY post submission, it will indicate an illegitimate user. Also hashing the CSRF token and tying it to the session id (assuming that is properly generated) is a better idea. By tying I mean that `hash("sha512", (session_id() + openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)));` works well.

Comment: why should i put session_start() in the token class its already defined in the index.php @echolocation

Comment: Because the function is a new instance, session_start() doesn't declare global variables, so it must be declared again for every function.

Comment: any thoughts why do i get an error: Undefined index: token in PhpProject22_CSRF\profile.php on line 12 @echolocation

Comment: Possibly because you're not checking if `$_POST['token']` is set

Comment: it seems that $_POST['token] is not set i dont know why @echolocation

Comment: Has a post request been submitted?

Comment: only if i add <input type='submit' value='check'> it work, can i do it without the submit button ? @echolocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When checking post you need to do the following:

```
if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && Token::check($_POST['token']){
        code
    }else{
        error
    }
}
```

If someone spoof the post, and doesn't include the token, you're going to get an undefined index error, because $_POST['token'] doesn't exist and you are referencing it.

Comment: Thank you it works but can i do it without the submit button, using only <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate();?>'>

Comment: Well, the form still needs to be submitted, so I suppose you could do it via javascript?